# Non-English characters as array key - "undefined index"

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of names which I am reading in from a mysql table. Everything works fine, except I've just noticed that if the name contains any non-English characters, e.g. Scandanavian, Greek etc. this causes an error, "undefined index".

What I don't get though is that the names are being listed out fine in another part of my app, using the same function. The only difference being that I am passing the name specifically as a parameter when this error occurs. Other times I am just iterating through the whole list and echoing out all the names.

Each name is the array key, I'm getting the error on the line for the else return:

```
   if($nameParam ==""){ 
         return $listOfNames;
   }
   else{ 
         return $listOfNames[$nameParam];   
   }
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Would it be better to somehow check each name and apply some kind of encoding/decoding writing/reading to the mysql table?  If so what would be the best way to do this? 
Thanks..

Comment: Please show us a `var_dump` of `$listOfNames` and `$nameParam`.

Comment: plz post var_dump here or on http://pastie.org/

Comment: var_dumps display both the array and individual names as expected, and the names are all listing out elsewhere in the app as expected. It seems the problem arises only when I want to access and then pass the value associated with the key onto another function. The only other difference is that I'm using ajax, but doing a dump of the $_GET also displays the name param as expected. I guess I'll just try encoding as suggested in answers below. I am only dealing with European and East European languages here.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Chances are you'll figure the problem out in the process.

Comment: It simply sounds like there's an encoding mismatch somewhere along the way. Don't wave the magic `utf8_encode` stick over if you're not aware of what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've looked through PHP C code for if PHP does modifies/strips unicode chars in array key strings in any way but couldn't find any conversion logic there.
Just to confirm this I've asked a question on php.net mailing list:

**Q:**
....blah blah...I was just wondering - when unicode characteres are used in
array key - does PHP strips them or affects them in any way?
or does PHP simply treats keys as binary string, the end of the story?

**A:**
I believe that string array keys are treated as binary strings, and
never modified. I couldn't find you a source, but I've always worked on
this assumption and never hit a problem. UTF-8 keys definitely work fine
(*); I'm also not aware of any max length the keys can have (meaning you
shouldn't have to worry about a multi-byte character getting truncated
in the middle).

Thus I now believe that having whatever UTF8 characters in array keys shouldn't affect your ability to use arrays as usual.

**ALSO**

I'm sure you already aware of this but I would check that db uses correct encoding to store data.
In mysql I always use **UTF-8** charset and **utf8_general_ci** collation.

Comment: A string is first and foremost a sequence of bytes. Even low-level bit shuffling is done on strings in PHP, like with the `pack` function. Even if UTF-8 uses more than one byte per character, it's also just a sequence of bytes. Unicode array keys work perfectly fine, as you could test for yourself: `$foo = array('あ' => 'bar'); echo $foo['あ'];`

Comment: @nix Can I ask you a question about the utf8_general_ci collation? I changed my table field to this as you suggested and it didn't seem to have any effect. But after entering new(similar) data to test with, the problem seems to be solved as there is no error for this new data, but the 'old' data still causes the same error. Should changing the collation not automatically update all the data for this field, or is it still defined by what it was when originally entered?

Comment: this article might help: http://www.bluebox.net/news/2009/07/mysql_encoding . But in the end if your product  at development stage yet - it might be easier to reload db data.

Comment: @nix answer accepted by the way, I will ask a new seperate question later because it seems this problem was just not defining the fields as utf8 to begin with. I appreciate your help. Thanks :)

Comment: @nix wow thanks for this article, this will be very helpful with understanding. Yeah still in development.